# React PropTypes. Force an Array to be of a specific React Type

Tags: arrays, reactjs, prop, react-proptypes

How can I force/validate that each item of a passed in Array prop (to a React Component), be of a specific React type?

Here is an example code for this:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">
    var MyButton = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (<input type="button" value={this.props.text} />);
        }
    });

    var MyButton2 = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (<input type="button" value={this.props.text} />);
        }
    });

var MyComp = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        //buttons: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(MyButton)  //Something like this
    },
    render: function() {
        return (<div><div>{this.props.title}</div>
            {this.props.buttons}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var buttons = [React.createElement(MyButton, {key:"3", text: "Save"})];
buttons.push(React.createElement(MyButton, {key: "1",text: "Cancel"}));
buttons.push(React.createElement(MyButton2, {key: "2",text: "Search"}));  // And don't allow this one

React.render(<MyComp title="My Window" buttons={buttons} />, document.getElementById('container'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [this good article](http://rjzaworski.com/2015/01/putting-react-custom-proptypes-to-work) about propTypes, you can write your own extension function that can be passed to `React.PropTypes.arrayOf`.

This is the example shown in the post referenced above for email:

```
var emailPropType = function (props, propName, component) {
  if (!isEmail(props[propName])) {
    return new Error('Invalid email!');
  }
};
```

Can be used like this:

```
var EmailList = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    emails: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(emailPropType).isRequired
  },
  render: function () {
    return React.DOM.ul(null, this.props.emails.map(function (email) {
      return React.DOM.li({ key: email }, email);
    }));
  }
});
```